# How do I enable Enable Error Squiggles on mac?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have tried finding the enable error Squiggles option on vs code but there isn't any. (C/C++)

Comment: What language are you writing in? It is a per-language configuration setting.

Comment: C.I went into the setting and searched for error squiggles cant find any